# HttpModule doesn't intercept POST to url (IIS 5.1)

Tags: iis, post, httpmodule

I have a simple web site (localhost/test) in IIS 5.1 with only a HttpModule and one aspx page.
When I browse the aspx page, the HttpModule works ok.
A POST with soapUI to the url of the aspx page (localhost/test/default.aspx) also works.
But a POST to the url of the web site (localhost/test) is not intercepted by the HttpModule.

What can I do to let the HttpModule react on all POST messages to the site.

Sorry when this is a beginner's question, but several days ago this worked on IIS 7.5 on another machine - has it got anything to do with the version of IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure IIS to send all requests through ASP.Net by [adding a wildcard mapping](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/).

Comment: Thank you for the anwer and link. I entered .* and copied the exe path (an exe that doesn't exist..) from another entry and it works.